# Minimal uncountable well-ordered set $S_{\Omega}$ and the sequence lemma

Tags: general-topology

Let $S_{\Omega}$ denote an uncountable well-ordered set every section of which is countable.

In Munkres' book Topology, it says on pg 181 that:

> $S_{\Omega}$ satisfies the sequence lemma: if $A$ is a subset of $S_{\Omega}$ and $y\in\overline A$, then there exists a sequence $\{a_n\}$ in $A$ such that $a_n \to y$

To prove this, I tried to construct a sequence $\{a_n\}$ by using the fact that the section $\{z\in S_\Omega \mid z < y\}$ is countable, but I am getting no where.

Munkres writes that the claim above can be "readily checked", yet I am stuck. How can I prove this?

Answer (score 3):

Suppose $y\in\overline{A}$. Then first convince yourself that one of the following must hold:

- Either $y\in A$ (boring), or
- $y\in \overline{A_y}$, where $A_y$ is the set of elements of $A$ which are $<y$ (if we are thinking of elements of $S_\Omega$ as ordinals, we could write this as "$A\cap y$").

If case one holds, we're done - take $a_n=y$. If case two holds, we need to think a little; we want a sequence of points which "climb all the way up $A_y$." To do this, we're going to use the fact that $A_y$ is countable. List the elements of $A_y$ as $A_y=\{a_0, a_1, a_2, . . .\}=\{a_i: i\in\mathbb{N}\}$; note that this is probably listing them out of order. That's fine.

Now first, show the following:

- For each $n$, we can find some $k$ such that $a_k\ge a_m$ for all $m<n$.

Finally: can we use this to build a sequence which climbs all the way up $A_y$? (HINT: can we ensure that the $n$th term of the sequence be bigger than each of $a_0, a_1, a_2, . . . , a_n$?)

Comment: It is not yet clear to me why the second case $y\in \overline {A_y}$ holds if the first case does not hold: if I assume to the contrary that $y\notin \overline {A_y}$, then there exists an interval $(z,w)$ containing $y$ which does not intersect $A_y$, but this just means that every element of $A_y$ must be "less than or equal to" $z$. am I missing something?

Comment: Remember, we're assuming that $y\in \overline{A}$ - if $y\not\in A\cup\overline{A}_y$, let $z$ be as you say and consider the interval $(z, y+1)$ . . .

Comment: What do you mean by $y+1$?

Comment: I mean the successor of $y$. (Since the set is well-ordered, $y$ does indeed have a successor.)

Comment: To show the claim: for each $n$, there exists $k$ such that $a_k \geq a_m$ for all $m < n$, can I do the following? For each $n$, I can order every $a_m$  for $m < n$ as $a_{n_1} < a_{n_2} < \dots,< a_{n_m}$ and let $k = {n_m}$

Comment: Sorry, I missed your comment; yes, that's right.